# Why Jquery became so used among all other libs

Tags: jquery, javascript

Once there were small javascript scripts. Then some little lib-like scripts apper. Then various they evolved, and now it seems to me that everyone uses jquery.

Everyone sugests "bla bla use jquery...". Is this really the best? Is it the final solution?

Comment: I don't mean to nitpick here but... [http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)

Comment: I don't think its nit-picky, your totally right in linking that. Probably should flag this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple reason - Visual Studio has addon for jquery, and cms designers use it.

Answer (score 2):

Of course not. The right tool is the one that helps **you** work efficiently. For a lot of people that's jQuery. For me it's [MooTools](http://mootools.net/). Try several, and use the one that you find the easiest and most useful. I have used several obscure JavaScript libraries before, such as [Midori](http://midorijs.com/), simply because they work for me.

Answer (score 1):

This question is *really* subjective. Here is a really great link that I think explains better than I could.

> jQuery is your best option if your
>   project primarily requires a level of
>   DOM manipulation, easier access to
>   Ajax (both dojo and jQuery support
>   deferrers), animation effects, hooks
>   or events. It’s also highly popular,
>   so if your company’s dev team are
>   attempting to hire, you *may* find
>   that there are more developers with
>   jQuery knowledge
>
> -Addy Osmani

http://addyosmani.com/blog/is-jquery-the-best-option-for-large-scale-app-development/

In fairness this is a direct comparison to Dojo. However I think it still has bearing.